# How to enable property type in Intellisense in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for C# language code.

I noticed that when intellisense opens for suggestion for getter setter properties in code editor, It doesn't shows dataType for suggested property in intellisense

Please help me how to enable datatype for variables and properties in Intellisense

Thanks

Comment: You mean the hint label?